# How to create a List of Dictionary Values?

Tags: python, dictionary

How would I make a list of Values of a dictionary? For example, if I had

```
{1:Apple,2:Red,3:Purple,4:Green}
```

How would I receive a list of

```
['Apple','Red','Purple','Green']
```

After fooling around on python for an hour I still can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 4):

Call [`.values()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) on the dictionary.

In Python 3, that'll return a [dict view](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views), so call `list()` on that.

Python 2:

```
>>> d = {1:'Apple', 2:'Red', 3:'Purple', 4:'Green'}
>>> d.values()
['Apple', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Green']
```

Python 3:

```
>>> d = {1:'Apple', 2:'Red', 3:'Purple', 4:'Green'}
>>> d.values()
dict_values(['Apple', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Green'])
>>> list(d.values())
['Apple', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Green']
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the OP, but my impression was that something more like `[d[k] for k in sorted(d)]` might be needed.

Comment: @DSM: Impossible to tell; what if the OP expects dictionaries to have ordering? As it stands, the OP asks for a list of the values from a dictionary, that's all we know.

Comment: I should have clarified that my apologies. I know how to order, just needed to figure out how to receive a list of my values.